# Why comparing two attributes type `float` and `int` with the same values get `False` in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point-comparison

Let's consider the code below

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.a = 0.0
        self.b = b
    def count_a(self):
        self.a += 0.1

foo = Foo(1)
for i in range(0, 15):
    foo.count_a()
    print "a =", foo.a, "b =", foo.b, '"a == b" ->', foo.a == foo.b
```

Output:

```
a = 0.2 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 0.4 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 0.6 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 0.8 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.0 b = 1 "a == b" -> True
a = 1.2 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.4 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.6 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.8 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.0 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.2 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.4 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.6 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.8 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
a = 3.0 b = 1 "a == b" -> False
```

But if I change code on line `11` to `foo = Foo(2)`, the output is turned to be:

```
a = 0.2 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 0.4 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 0.6 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 0.8 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.0 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.2 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.4 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.6 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 1.8 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.0 b = 2 "a == b" -> False *
a = 2.2 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.4 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.6 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 2.8 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
a = 3.0 b = 2 "a == b" -> False
```

You will see that the output `a = 2.0 b = 2 "a == b" -> False` is totally weird. I think I might misunderstand some concept of OOP in Python. Please explain to me why this unexpected output is happened and how to solve this problem.

Comment: This is because of floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: You can use the `Decimal` class.

Comment: Try `0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1` in the REPL

Comment: This is a good reference:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing  to do with Object Orientation - it has to do with the way computers represent floating point numbers internally, and rounding errors.
http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

The Python specificity here is the default string representation of floating point numbers, which will round them at less decimal places than the internal representation for pretty printing.

Although, for people needing correct comparisons, respecting the scale of floating point numbers, Python has introduced a nice mechanism with [PEP 485](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/), which added the `math.isclose` function to the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the, correct, explanation by jsbueno, remember that Python often allows casting of "basic types" to themselves.

i.e. str("a") == "a"

So, if you need a workaround in addition to the reason, just convert your int/float mix to all floats and test those.

```
a = 2.0 
b = 2 
print "a == b", float(a) == float(b)
```

output:

```
a == b True
```

Comment: One should probably still make the epsilon comparison (abs(a-b)<epsilon). I'm not sure if there isn't a car where this doesn't work. Even if there isn't, it's good to remind beginners that this is the standard way to check for equality of floats.

Comment: As I've said, Python incorporates the "isclose" function which takes care of using a relative comparison by default - so it is valid for floats >> 10 and floats << 1 without one having to worry about picking an apropriate epsilon for each situation. (And it also works with a fixed epsilon if one's usecase demand so)